# Three.js rendered model looks different from Blender rendered model

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, blender, react-three-fiber

There is a big difference in terms of looks and lighting between the model in Three.js and the model in Blender. I'm using the latest versions of `Next.js` with `React Three Fiber` at the time of writing this. The following are the steps to reproduce the problem.

### 1. Exporting a `.GLB` file from Blender to Three.js. These are the export settings.

[image: Blender export settings]

### 2. Code to render the model

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useLoader, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import { DRACOLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader";


const GltfModel = ({ rotation, ...props }) => {
    const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, "./fish_stall_2.glb", (loader) => {
        const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
        dracoLoader.setDecoderPath("../static/js/gltf/");
        loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);
    })

    const ref = useRef();
    const object = gltf.scene;

    // Subscribe this component to the render-loop, rotate the mesh every frame
    // rotation is updated by passing the "rotation" prop
    useFrame((state, delta) => {
        ref.current.rotation.x = rotation.x;
        ref.current.rotation.y = rotation.y;
    });

    return (
        <>
            <primitive
                ref={ref}
                object={object}
                {...props}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default GltfModel;
```

### 3. [Here is the result of the website](https://recordit.co/4meFLrFLOE)

and this is the expected render (render images from Blender):
[image: Rendered Blender image of the user's home photo 1]
[image: Rendered Blender image of the user's home photo 2]
[image: Rendered Blender image of the front fish store photo 1]
[image: Rendered Blender image of the front fish store photo 2]

Furthermore, I've tried using [GLTF Report](https://gltf.report/) and it still renders it looking completely different from the image renders in Blender. Though in the report, there are quite a fair bit of level 2 severity errors. However, I don't think that is the main reason why the model renders differently.

I'm really lost. Searched on Google to check if others have faced similar problems. They have, but to no solution. I'm seeking help/some level of direction to where I can make the rendered images in Blender look like the one on the website using Three.js.

[Here is the link to the Blender file of the model in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dDNrUsaAQBo1YnlLuy5ari2UyycvuJy2/view)

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: The Blender rendering pipeline is completely different than a real-time rendering like Three.js. It looks like you have very soft shadows and several light sources, which is easy to do in Blender, but much harder to achieve in real-time. You could achieve this softer illumination look by making it a part of your textures. I recommend you [read about "baking lights"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9993/what-does-it-mean-to-bake-lights) and maybe [watch a few tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F73WLkm0Qm0) on lightmap baking.

Comment: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/canvas check out these `<Canvas />` props, and what they are doing (`flat` = disable tonemapping, linear = disables automatic sRGB encoding, also legacy color mode but probably don't want to change that), make sure everything is using sRGB flow, i think GLTFLoader sets your glb textures to `.encoding: sRGBEncoding` automatically.  try having the only lighting come from this and see if the colors look better `<Environment preset='warehouse' />` also watch this about the color stuff https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=texTxhcfEkY